# Data Factory V2 - maxconcurrency is limiting backfilling

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm finding that the maxConcurrency for a tumbling window trigger is limiting the number of backfilled slices.

e.g. maxConcurrency = 50 (the upper limit), I can only backfill 50 weeks.

I'd expect maxConcurrency to limit the number of in-progress slices, but I'd still expect the other backfilled weeks to be scheduled.

If I remember correctly from the V1 days, backfilling kicks in after a new deployment (and I think other reasons, which I can't seem to find the site describing it now)... Is there a way I can cause / trick the other slices to be scheduled?

Poking around the powershell commands, I only see ways to redefine a trigger not any explicit things around re-scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Ooo, correction. Looking again, it looks like the next batch has scheduled approximately 1 hour 1/2 after the first batch. Interestingly not after they completed, as each pipeline run (50 of them) took about 5 minutes.

Is there some internal logic causing the next batch to be scheduled? Or is perhaps one of the other parameters having a knock on impact of the 1 hour 1/2 setting? I'm unsure, I'll update this answer if I discover it.